Vue.js Vuex State Not Syncing Across Tabs and Direct URL Access
I have a Vue.js application with a login component and a settings page. When I log in and navigate to the settings page via the menu within the login page, the Vuex store updates correctly, and I can see the updated user information on the settings page.
However, if I open the settings page in a new tab or access it directly by typing the URL into the address bar or comming back to it after loginin via go_back symbol, it displays outdated user information from before the login.
(note that when i press on login ,i get token and userinformations and update the store)
is this problem normal,does it related to my project or it is how vuejs and router works,how i can solve it?
